# Время выполнения echo sprinf

Tags: php, laravel, echo

laravel 6,
php 7.4,
homested под windos (домашняя среда),
linux centos (продакшен).

По сути вопрос простой. Есть вывод:

```
echo sprintf('eqfeed_callback(%s)', json_encode($data));
```

при размере массива 1673920 байт (500 элементов) echo выполняется 1,2 сек
при размере массива 12551386 байт (15000 элементов) echo выполняется 9,6 сек
Замеры проводились дома под win. На хосте меньше, но все равно много.
У меня возник вопрос почему так много ) ? Ну и соответсвенно, можно ли это время уменьшить? Буду благодарен за идеи и соображения по этому вопросу. Данные приводить здесь не буду, это текст en и кириллица. Кириллица соответственно выглядит так:

```
\u0425\u0430\u0440\u044c\u043a\u043e\u0432
```

Comment: А отдельно померить echo, sprintf и json_encode мысль в голову не приходила?

Comment: приходила, именно echo

Comment: а без ларваеля? и если только под ним тормоза, то почему не используются штатные средства вывода? А если без, то под центосью тоже что ли не php_fpm, а mod_php?

Comment: sprintf - 0.051669120788574 сек,

json_encode - 0.049652099609375 сек.

Comment: без ларавеля в данном случае никак, да конечно php_fpm и mod могут дать разное время, да и сервер если "прокачать". Интересен сам факт, мне показалось, что это долго

Comment: никому не интересен сам "факт". интересно только разобраться в причинах. Поэтому ещё раз: есть ли разница между ларавелем и без? если нет - какая конфигурация сервера? Если есть - почему не используются штатные средства ларавеля для вывода жсон?

Comment: без ларавеля к сожалению я не проверял. Мне интересен сам факт. Сервер:  AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor
 MemTotal:       65897500 kB
этот массив передается в колбек скрипта google maps, за сим echo. Return одинаковый результат. Не в коем случае не настаиваю на ответах, если "никому не интересен сам "факт". Спасибо

Comment: Stack Overflow  - сайт для вопросов, а не для "самфактов"

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/523321)